Add own character encoding to PSPad , Notepad++ VS-Studio
I have to work on a very exotic erp system which stores all files in its own character encoding.
I would like to edit files with a modern text editor like PSPad, Notepad++ VS-Studio, since the build in texteditor of that erp system lacks a lot of funtionality.
Actualy even Notepad.exe would be a better choice!
Most characters are recognised correctly in PSPad and Notepad++ but some characters are displayed wrong.
ÄÖÜ
äöüß
abcdefg
!"§$%&/()=?`';#

will be shown in PSPad as

in HEX it looks like:
8E99 9A0A 8494 81E1 0A61 6263 6465 6667 0A21 22F5 2425 262F 2829 3D3F 6027 3B23 0A

Any idea, how I could edit this files in a modern text editor?

This seems Cp850, DOS Latin-1. Notepad++ West-European OEM 850. These single byte character sets depend on the local system locale, so in Germany is different than elsewhere

Maybe you should consider conversion in both directions.

You're right. CP850 is the right character set. I tried everything except this one. CP850 seems to work. THX!
